# How to fix this the problem of "argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"?

Tags: python

I tried to solve a Python exercise but my program blows up while runing.

The exercise instructions are:

> Open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line. For each line, split
> the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program
> should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see
> if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list.
> When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in
> alphabetical order.

Here is my code:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
j=-1
glolist=list()
for line in fh:
    line=line.rstrip()
    lst=line.split()
    nb=len(lst)
    i=0
    while i< nb:
        if lst[i] not in glolist:    #argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"
            i=i+1
        else:
            j=i
            i=i+1
    if j==-1:
        glolist=glolist+lst
    else:
        h=0
        while h<j:
            glolist=lst.append(lst[h])
            h=h+1
        h=h+1
        while h<nb:
            glolist=lst.append(lst[h])
            h=h+1
glolist=glolist.sort()
print(glolist)
```

Comment: I haven't looked in detail, but that is not how you use `sort`.

Comment: When you have `glolist=lst.append(lst[h])` you are saying `glolist = None`. Now `glolist` is no longer a `list`.

Comment: you are getting `None` for lst at line `lst=line.split()`

Comment: @AmitNanaware `split` never returns `None`

Comment: @AmitNanaware how? That method returns a list. Problem is this line: `glolist=lst.append(lst[h])`, the append method doesn't return the list.

Comment: Okay looks like @quamrana has found the actual problem. But note that you will have a similar problem later with the use of `sort`. In both cases, these methods that do an in-place modification to the list return `None`.

Comment: @alani i dont't think that @quamrana answer is right 'cause the program blows up befor that line. the problem is at line ` if lst[i] not in glolist` but i don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Thanks everyone.i have  fixed the error . the problm is due to the bad  use of both function `append()` & `sort()` (there is no affectation). and i've just noticed that the program returned after rectification rewrite the repititive words as in the file  & i rectified this .ps: for those who are interested here is the finel rectified code:

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
words=list()
for line in fh:
    line=line.rstrip()
    lst=line.split()
    i=0
    while i<len(lst):
        str=lst[i]
        if str in words:
            i=i+1
        else:
            words.append(str)
            i=i+1
words.sort()
print(words)
```